# Suggestion GWT High Scale Application Server

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt, glassfish

Currently I am working on a Large Scale Application which uses GWT with Hibenate. We are facing some performance issues with existing Jetty / Tomcat server. And we want a another server that handles hibernate queries and GWT both perfectly.

Problem with tomcat is it sometimes stops responding GWT requests, and client hangs up on some points.

There are certain servers that comes in my mind like :
GlassFish
Jboss
IBM WebSphere AS
etc.

Please suggest some high scale server that handles GWT RPC request well and can run in multi-client environment well. We are expecting 100 concurrent users, Hardware is not an issue.

Thanking You,
Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your problem is not related to Tomcat or Hibernate. Your application should have scalebility problem. I do suggest you to investigate your application before investing to a fancy application server.

Comment: Yes, 100 concurrent users is no load for a tomcat server. You really should check your application for bottlenecks!

Comment: @gursel : thankx for your response. We have checked the application well and its according to standards. Does it possible that tomcat may have problem with GWT RPC ? I have only worked with Glassfish, Jetty and Jboss but not on large scale. Your help is much appropriated, Please help. Edit : We are using tomcat 6.

Comment: We are also using GWT and Tomcat together. I did lots of load tests, and tomcat performs very well. You should investigate tomcat stack trace when it hungs..

Comment: @gursel : I have tried that, it showz blank !... No response. with hibernate my show_sql is also true so if any background hibernate is going on than that will also be display, but it doesn't give any response for some particular time, actually we are investigating on which method or call it hangs, simultaneously I am investigation on other server to try with.

Comment: if you are using linux or unix, you can easily get stack trace of tomcat , by using kill -3  pid(tomcat java process).. if you are using windows, you can use jconsole to get stack trace.

Comment: If you would inform me about the consequences, I would be quite happy.